# Check if div there after click, remove it if it was there

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript which is create a type of accordion, I would like to open `div`s on click and then close them on a second click. I could done that but then I don't know where to insert the removing code `el.classList.remove("openDiv");` to close all tabs that might was open and the only tab which should be open is the clicked one.

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('applications');
var i;
var action = 1;

function addHandler(el) {
   el.addEventListener("click", function() {

     if ( action == 1 ) {
       el.classList.add('openDiv');
       action = 2;
     } else {
       el.classList.remove("openDiv");
       action = 1;
     }
   });
}

for (i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
   addHandler(el[i]);
}
```

I also created a [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LGgGEZ)

Comment: accordian is working in your pen, what is not working?

Comment: @gurvinder372 reread the question

Comment: do not use a global variable to store the state of the div as that variable is shared and used by all the divs. Use a class, add it to the opened div and then close all the other div that has the open class

Comment: That part is fine, but I want to close any tabs which wasn't click, if there were any open. For example if I clicked on the blue one and then the red one, it should close the blue one and so on

Comment: Hey @BeNdErR! Yeah that's the part I am not sure how to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('applications');
var i;

function addHandler(el) {
  el.addEventListener("click", function() {

     //updated condition for click
     if ( !this.classList.contains('openDiv')) {
        var a = document.getElementsByClassName('openDiv');
        for (var i in a) {
          if (a[i].classList) {
            a[i].classList.remove("openDiv");
          }
        }
        el.classList.add('openDiv');
        action = 2;
    } else {
        el.classList.remove("openDiv");
        action = 1;
    }

  });
}

for (i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
  addHandler(el[i]);
}
```

[Working demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KVGVdb)

Comment: Hey @RadecPech! Thank you, but it seems like you need to click twice before it makes the change between the tabs

Comment: @RadecPech: That's what I looked for! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I've edited a little your code, find an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/48Lpvmbr/2/

code:

```
var els = document.getElementsByClassName('applications');

function addHandler(el) {
  el.addEventListener("click", function() {

     for(var x = 0; x < els.length; x++){
        if(els[x] === el){
            console.log("NOT ME!!!");
        }else{
            els[x].classList.remove("openDiv");
        }
     }

     if(el.classList.contains("openDiv")){
        el.classList.remove("openDiv");
     }else{
        el.classList.add("openDiv");
     }

  });
}

for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
  addHandler(els[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('applications');
var i;

function addHandler(el) {
  el.addEventListener("click", function() {
     el.classList.toggle('openDiv');
      removeOpen(el);
  });
}

function removeOpen(openElement){
  for (i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
   if(el[i] !== openElement){
     el[i].classList.remove("openDiv");
   }
  }
}

for (i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
  addHandler(el[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed up your code a little to have a wrapper element around the content so there is only one event listener. But basically you need to select the open elements and than remove the class.

```js
var wrapper = document.getElementById("application_wrapper");
wrapper.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
  var elem = evt.target; //get what was clicked
  if (elem.nodeName === "H2") { //see if it was an h2
    elem.classList.toggle("open");
    
    //now to remove
    var opened = wrapper.querySelectorAll("h2.open");  //find opened
    for(var i=opened.length-1; i>=0;i--) { //loop
        if (opened[i]==elem) continue; //make sure we do not remove the one we just added
        opened[i].classList.remove("open");
    }        
  }
});
```

```css
h2 + h1,
h2 + h1 + p {
  display: none;
}
h2.open + h1,
h2.open + h1 + p {
  display: block;
}

.applications { border: 1px solid black; }
h1{ border-top: 1px solid #CCC; } 
h2{cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<div id="application_wrapper">
  <div class="applications" id="colorCos">
    <h2>Color Cosmetics</h2>
    <h1>Color Cosmetics</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque tincidunt ultrices arcu, ut pulvinar risus maximus sed. Quisque dolor nisl, iaculis id sem eget, molestie mollis est. Phasellus scelerisque sagittis ex, nec vestibulum turpis euismod
      eu. Aliquam aliquet orci et sapien euismod, vitae pellentesque velit porttitor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Proin rhoncus, felis non elementum ultrices, dui nisl tincidunt risus, sit
      amet sodales nunc dolor semper lacus. Vivamus egestas lectus id imperdiet pharetra. Nulla non sem elit. Fusce porta velit leo, nec gravida ligula auctor vitae. Sed justo sem, sodales ut imperdiet at, fringilla pharetra neque.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="applications" id="hairCare">
    <h2>Hair Care</h2>
    <h1>Hair Care</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque tincidunt ultrices arcu, ut pulvinar risus maximus sed. Quisque dolor nisl, iaculis id sem eget, molestie mollis est. Phasellus scelerisque sagittis ex, nec vestibulum turpis euismod
      eu. Aliquam aliquet orci et sapien euismod, vitae pellentesque velit porttitor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Proin rhoncus, felis non elementum ultrices, dui nisl tincidunt risus, sit
      amet sodales nunc dolor semper lacus. Vivamus egestas lectus id imperdiet pharetra. Nulla non sem elit. Fusce porta velit leo, nec gravida ligula auctor vitae. Sed justo sem, sodales ut imperdiet at, fringilla pharetra neque.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="applications" id="babyCare">
    <h2>Baby Care</h2>
    <h1>Baby Care</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque tincidunt ultrices arcu, ut pulvinar risus maximus sed. Quisque dolor nisl, iaculis id sem eget, molestie mollis est. Phasellus scelerisque sagittis ex, nec vestibulum turpis euismod
      eu. Aliquam aliquet orci et sapien euismod, vitae pellentesque velit porttitor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Proin rhoncus, felis non elementum ultrices, dui nisl tincidunt risus, sit
      amet sodales nunc dolor semper lacus. Vivamus egestas lectus id imperdiet pharetra. Nulla non sem elit. Fusce porta velit leo, nec gravida ligula auctor vitae. Sed justo sem, sodales ut imperdiet at, fringilla pharetra neque.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="applications" id="skinCare">
    <h2>Skin Care</h2>
    <h1>Skin Care</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque tincidunt ultrices arcu, ut pulvinar risus maximus sed. Quisque dolor nisl, iaculis id sem eget, molestie mollis est. Phasellus scelerisque sagittis ex, nec vestibulum turpis euismod
      eu. Aliquam aliquet orci et sapien euismod, vitae pellentesque velit porttitor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Proin rhoncus, felis non elementum ultrices, dui nisl tincidunt risus, sit
      amet sodales nunc dolor semper lacus. Vivamus egestas lectus id imperdiet pharetra. Nulla non sem elit. Fusce porta velit leo, nec gravida ligula auctor vitae. Sed justo sem, sodales ut imperdiet at, fringilla pharetra neque.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="applications" id="soap">
    <h2>Soap & Bath</h2>
    <h1>Soap & Bath</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque tincidunt ultrices arcu, ut pulvinar risus maximus sed. Quisque dolor nisl, iaculis id sem eget, molestie mollis est. Phasellus scelerisque sagittis ex, nec vestibulum turpis euismod
      eu. Aliquam aliquet orci et sapien euismod, vitae pellentesque velit porttitor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Proin rhoncus, felis non elementum ultrices, dui nisl tincidunt risus, sit
      amet sodales nunc dolor semper lacus. Vivamus egestas lectus id imperdiet pharetra. Nulla non sem elit. Fusce porta velit leo, nec gravida ligula auctor vitae. Sed justo sem, sodales ut imperdiet at, fringilla pharetra neque.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```